# Johnson Nyquist noise with voltage driving

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, noise

In his 1928 paper, Nyquist derives the famous Johnson-Nyquist noise relation which is, to be very precise according to his paper:

It gives the variance of the voltage at the boundary of a resistor that is at thermal equilibrium, and connected to another resistor through a waveguide. Basically, we have $<U(\nu)^2>d \nu=4*R*k_b T d \nu$

He also generalizes it if instead of two resistor one of them is a "general" impedance $Z=R_\nu+i Y_\nu$ where $R_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ might depend on frequency. The result is then: $<U(\nu)^2> d \nu=4*k_b T R(\nu)_{\nu} d \nu$

Let's assume that we now have an impedance $Z$ driven by a voltage, in contact with a bath at temperature $T$. How do we know that this Johnson-Nyquist relation still holds ? Indeed the derivation is done in a very particular setup, without driving.